# Show ToolTip of disabled and read-only Combobox

Tags: c#, wpf

I am currently facing the problem that my disbaled `ComboBox`, which does have a tooltip won't show when I am hovering it with my mouse. The tooltip shows correctly when the `ComboBox` is not disabled.

The code of the `ComboBox` is:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableItems}" 
          SelectedValue="{Binding Item, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
          IsReadOnly="{Binding IsDeletable, Converter={StaticResource BooleanInverter}}"
          IsEnabled="{Binding IsDeletable}" 
          IsHitTestVisible="{Binding IsDeletable}" 
          ToolTip="{Binding Item.ConcatenatedNameInterchanged}" 
          ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True" />
```

The bound values are:

- `IsReadOnly = True`
- `IsEnabled = False`
- `IsHitTestVisible = False`
- `ToolTip = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."`

I have tried to:

- set [`ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.controls.tooltipservice.showondisabled) in the default style, without success.
- hard-code `IsHitTestVisible="True"`, without success.

Do you have any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `IsHitTestVisible=false` is bad idea to show tooltip. You can *cheat* by creating tooltip on the container (e.g. `Border` with transparent background) if you just want to disable mouse interaction with the child.

Comment: @Sinatr It still does not work after removing `IsHitTestVisible` completely from the ComboBox.

Comment: have you tried using C# code  _ToolTipService.SetShowOnDisabled(myCombobox, true);_